# Trying to play video on scroll event (addEventListener("scroll",...) React Javascript (NotAllowedError)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to automatically play video on scroll down, (similar to tiktok).

On the computer, everything works fine. But when I scroll down on mobile, I get "NotAllowedError". This is because mobile doesn't allow autoplay when video is not muted (I checked the code if video is muted, and it works). So I need it to play automatically on scroll unmuted video.

So to play video on mobile, there has to be some user interaction.

I created this code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    var video = document.getElementById("video1");
    video.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, true);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, true);
    };
  });
```

Though when I scroll it doesn't register and doesn't run the handleScroll code.

This code works:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, true);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, true);
    };
  });
```

But it doesn't work on mobile. It gives the "NotAllowedError", which I believe is because it's using "window." instead of "video." (video1 is the id tag of the video). So it's not reading the window scroll as an action (that's my best guess right now).

So I need to make the code work for the "video.addEventListener..." code actually pick up the scrolling action from the user.

I have heard to fix this, to delete the "height:100%" values in CSS. This didn't work. I actually deleted all the CSS code for both the overall code and the video code, and it still didn't trigger "video.addEventListener..." on scroll.

I am looking to get this working, when I scroll, to play video. Any knowledge/experience is appreciated.

EDIT:
From what I've seen after posting this, this idea won't work. At this point I'm trying to find a way to play and then pause all videos at once after one click event.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not passed dependency array (2nd argument to 'useEffect')

```js
useEffect( () => {
// add event listener
// return event listener
}, []);
```

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't have any dependencies so I didn't include that part. Though I've tested both ways and it works the same either way.